# Проблема с дубликатами C#

Tags: c#

Всем привет, я новичок и столкнулся с проблемой моего решения. Дана строка по типу "130 12 111 508 54 78 1110". Каждое число в строке имеет свой "вес", который состоит из сумы цифр. Например 130 имеет "вес" 4, т.к. 1+3+0 = 4. Все числа в строке - положительные. Задача вернуть строку, отсортированную "по весу", но при этом сохраняя первоначальный вид числа.

К примеру строка "130 12 111 508 54 78 1110" станет "111 1110 12 130 54 508 78"

У меня вышел такой код

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(Order("130 12 111 508 54 78 1110"));
        }

        public static string Order(string input)
        {

            string[] Subs = input.Split(' ', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).ToArray();

            Dictionary<string, int> Orders = new Dictionary<string, int>();

            foreach(string sub in Subs)
            {
                Orders.Add(sub, ReturnSumOfString(sub));
            }

            Orders = Orders.OrderBy(pair => pair.Value).ThenBy(pair => pair.Key).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);

            StringBuilder newstr = new StringBuilder("");
            foreach (var num in Orders)
            {
                newstr.Append(num.Key + " ");
            }
            
            return newstr.ToString();
        }

        public static int ReturnSumOfString(string input)
        {
            int[] vs = input.ToCharArray().Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToArray();
            return vs.Sum();
        }
```

И он вроде работает правильно, но я столкнулся с проблемой, что он не будет работать, если в строке повторяются числа. Проблема как я понял, в словаре, что он не может иметь двух одинаковых ключей, на которых завязано моё решение с сопоставлением чисел. Как можно решить проблему с повторениями?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я бы на вашем месте тогда хранил бы словарь, где ключ - это сумма цифр, а значение = это список чисел с такой сумоой.

Код

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Order("130 12 111 508 54 78 1110 1110"));
}

public static string Order(string input)
{
    string[] subs = input.Split().ToArray();

    var orders =  new Dictionary<int, List<string>>();

    foreach (string sub in subs)
    {
        var sum = ReturnSumOfString(sub);
        if (!orders.ContainsKey(sum)) orders[sum] = new List<string>();
        orders[sum].Add(sub);
    }

    var ordered = orders.OrderBy(x=>x.Key).SelectMany(x=>x.Value);

    StringBuilder newstr = new StringBuilder("");
    foreach (var num in ordered)
    {
        newstr.Append(num + " ");
    }

    return newstr.ToString();
}

public static int ReturnSumOfString(string input)
{
    int[] vs = input.ToCharArray().Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToArray();
    return vs.Sum();
}
```

Вывод

```
12 111 1110 1110 130 54 508 78
```

Comment: Благодарю за объяснение. Решение было простым, но мне додуматься та ещё задача!

Answer (score 0):

Есть ещё более короткий вариант, но он опирается на факт, что linq сортировка сама по себе стабильная.

```
void Main()
{
    Console.WriteLine(Order("130 12 111 508 54 78 1110 1110"));
}

public static string Order(string input)
{
    string[] subs = input.Split();  
    var ordered = subs.OrderBy(x=>ReturnSumOfString(x));

    StringBuilder newstr = new StringBuilder("");
    foreach (var num in ordered)    
        newstr.Append(num + " ");   

    return newstr.ToString();
}

public static int ReturnSumOfString(string input)
{
    int[] vs = input.ToCharArray().Select(x => int.Parse(x.ToString())).ToArray();
    return vs.Sum();
}
```

Вывод

```
12 111 1110 1110 130 54 508 78
```

Можно также закешировать суммы чисел, чтобы много раз не пересчитывать, результат будет тот же

```
var ordered = subs.Select(x=>(v:x, sum:ReturnSumOfString(x))).OrderBy(x=>x.sum);
```